# DBCC CHECKIDENT Sets Identity to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this code to reset the identity on a table:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

This works fine most of the time, with the first insert I do inserting 1 into the Id column. However, if I drop the DB and recreate it (using scripts I've written) and then call DBCC CHECKIDENT, the first item inserted will have an ID of 0.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After researching I found out I didn't read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817(SQL.80).aspx) properly - "The current identity value is set to the new_reseed_value. If no rows have been inserted to the table since it was created, the first row inserted after executing DBCC CHECKIDENT will use new_reseed_value as the identity. Otherwise, the next row inserted will use new_reseed_value + 1. "

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69116039/861716

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you pointed out in your question it is a [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817(SQL.80).aspx). I still find it strange though. I use to repopulate the test database and even though I do not rely on the values of identity fields it was a bit of annoying to have different values when populating the database for the first time from scratch and after removing all data and populating again.

A possible solution is to use **truncate** to clean the table instead of delete. But then you need to drop all the constraints and recreate them afterwards

In that way it always behaves as a newly created table and there is no need to call DBCC CHECKIDENT. The first identity value will be the one specified in the table definition and it will be the same no matter if you insert the data for the first time or for the N-th

Comment: that link seems to be dead, the current documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx, says that is only expected behavior for versions prior to 2012, but that doesn't seem to be true (testing on 2012 version, compatibility set to 2012, still seeing issue).

Answer (score 81):

You are right in what you write in the edit of your question.

After running `DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0)`:
- Newly created tables will start with identity 0
- Existing tables will continue with identity 1

The solution is in the script below, it's sort of a poor-mans-truncate :)

```
-- Remove all records from the Table
DELETE FROM TableName

-- Use sys.identity_columns to see if there was a last known identity value
-- for the Table. If there was one, the Table is not new and needs a reset
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'TableName' AND last_value IS NOT NULL) 
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName, RESEED, 0);
```

Comment: Very good but when dealing with multiple schemas you may want to tweak this a little to match on `object_id` instead of using `OBJECT_NAME()` to look up the table's name:  `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Schema.TableName') AND last_value IS NOT NULL`)

Answer (score 8):

It seems ridiculous that you can't set/reset an identity column with a single command to cover both cases of whether or not the table has had records inserted. I couldn't understand the behavior I was experiencing until I stumbled across this question on SO!

My solution (ugly but works) is to explicitly check the `sys.identity_columns.last_value` table (which tells you whether or not the table has had records inserted) and call the appropriate `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command in each case. It is as follows:

```
DECLARE @last_value INT = CONVERT(INT, (SELECT last_value FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MyTable'));
IF @last_value IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- Table newly created and no rows inserted yet; start the IDs off from 1
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, 1);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Table has rows; ensure the IDs continue from the last ID used
        DECLARE @lastValUsed INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM MyTable);
        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('MyTable', RESEED, @lastValUsed);
    END
```

Answer (score 5):

Change statement to

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 1)
```

This will start from 2 (or 1 when you recreate table), but it will never be 0.

Answer (score 4):

I did this as an experiment to reset the value to 0 as I want my first identity column to be 0  and it's working.

```
dbcc CHECKIDENT(MOVIE,RESEED,0)
dbcc CHECKIDENT(MOVIE,RESEED,-1)
DBCC CHECKIDENT(MOVIE,NORESEED)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename)
BEGIN
    DELETE from  tablename
    DBCC checkident ('tablename', reseed, 0)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

See also here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/06/26/fun-with-dbcc-chekident.aspx

This is documented behavior, why do you run CHECKIDENT if you recreate the table, in that case skip the step or use TRUNCATE (if you don't have FK relationships)

Answer (score 2):

I have used this in SQL to set IDENTITY to a particular value:-

```
DECLARE @ID int = 42;
DECLARE @TABLENAME  varchar(50) = 'tablename'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000) = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = '''+@TABLENAME+''' AND last_value IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        DBCC CHECKIDENT('+@TABLENAME+', RESEED,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID-1)+');
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DBCC CHECKIDENT('+@TABLENAME+', RESEED,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID)+');
    END';
EXEC (@SQL);
```

And this in C# to set a particular value:-

```
SetIdentity(context, "tablename", 42);
.
.
private static void SetIdentity(DbContext context, string table,int id)
{
    string str = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = '" + table
        + "' AND last_value IS NOT NULL)\nBEGIN\n";
    str += "DBCC CHECKIDENT('" + table + "', RESEED," + (id - 1).ToString() + ");\n";
    str += "END\nELSE\nBEGIN\n";
    str += "DBCC CHECKIDENT('" + table + "', RESEED," + (id).ToString() + ");\n";
    str += "END\n";
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(str);
}
```

This builds on the above answers and always makes sure the next value is 42 (in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from Zyphrax's answer ...

```
USE DatabaseName

DECLARE @ReseedBit BIT = 
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, ic.last_value))
                FROM sys.identity_columns ic
                INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ic.object_id = t.object_id), 0)
DECLARE @Reseed INT = 
CASE 
    WHEN @ReseedBit = 0 THEN 1 
    WHEN @ReseedBit = 1 THEN 0 
END

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.table_name', RESEED, @Reseed);
```

Caveats:
This is intended for use in reference data population situations where a DB is being initialized with enum type definition tables, where the ID values in those tables must always start at 1. The first time the DB is being created (e.g. during SSDT-DB publishing) @Reseed must be 0, but when resetting the data i.e. removing the data and re-inserting it, then @Reseed must be 1. So this code is intended for use in a stored procedure for resetting the DB data, which can be called manually but is also called from the post-deployment script in the SSDT-DB project. In that way the reference data inserts are only defined in one place but aren't restricted to be used only in post-deployment during publishing, they are also available for subsequent use (to support dev and automated test etc.) by calling the stored procedure to reset the DB back to a known good state.

Comment: there is an easier way of doing the same thing, pardon my formatting.   DECLARE @Reseed INT = (SELECT TOP 1
        CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(BIGINT, ic.last_value) > 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END as reseed
        FROM sys.identity_columns ic
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON ic.object_id = t.object_id and t.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName))

Answer (score -2):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 0);  
GO 



AdventureWorks2012=Your databasename
Person.AddressType=Your tablename
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything different than OP already does. Where's the solution?