# Identity reset issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, identity-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL server identity column values start at 0 instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724668/sql-server-identity-column-values-start-at-0-instead-of-1)

Inserted identity value starts from "0"

Here I'll create a database and create a table, now I'll try to delete the records in the empty table and reset the identity. When i insert the records now its starts from identity value "0".

```
CREATE DATABASE test

GO

USE test

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1]
  (
      [Rollno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Images] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [Rollno] ASC
    )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
  )ON [PRIMARY]

USE test

DELETE TABLE table1

DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 0)

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('Sachin')

SELECT * FROM table1
```

Could any one please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Resolve what? You didn't ask a question. What issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Help you to resolve what? I'm not sure what the question is... You've said what you're trying to do, and you've posted some code, and then made a comment that seems to suggest it's been successful. What's the problem?

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 0) is correct.  The next value is taken.  Just tested.  DELETE TABLE table1 is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 1)`

The last argument is the next value to use for the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

You are reseeding the identity value to 0, so this is the expected behaviour.