# How to keep identity while taking backup of database

Tags: sql-server

After taking the backup of database, when i tried to restore it, the seed of identity is reset to `0`. So when i try to insert any new values, the `id` (primary key) is started `1`.

Now the issue is, i have relational data tables. let say from `table x` after some operation the data is moved to `table y`. But as the seed is set to 0, the values of id of `table x` and `table y` clashes. and that gives me error.

Is there a any way while taking the backup, we can save the value of identity also.

P.S. :

1. size of database is huge and manual alteration is next to
   impossible.
2. seed of identity is reset to `0` only when the table is empty.

Edit :

Sorry for a bit confusion, by backup, i mean export (my bad). as the empty tables's seed is set to default, primary key in my tables are clashing, so with export of database, i need to store the values of identity of every table also.

Is there any way i can do that ?

Comment: Take a read of this one, may help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163876/restoring-database-backup-makes-identity-column-start-at-1-again

Comment: This is not normal backup or restore behavior. Make sure your tool or script isn't causing the reset.

Comment: @Leonidas199x already gone through that. but that post didn't helped a lot.

Comment: @MWillemse sorry for mistake, i am using backup, i am exporting database.

Comment: Use `DBCC CHECKIDENT('<table name>' RESEED)` (no third parameter) to have SQL server find out what the next value should be.

Comment: I am having around 100 tables. it is not feasible to fire the DBCC CHECKIDENT on every table. @MWillemse

Answer (score 2):

The identity seed is *not* reset or modified when using

- BACKUP DATABASE
- RESTORE DATABASE

You must be exporting and importing data, which is *not* backup and restore.
I say again

- BACKUP DATABASE is the **only** way to backup the database
- RESTORE DATABASE is the **only** way to restore the database,

If you want to keep export/import method, then simply use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql) to reset the seed.

Also read this to see why the seed is set to zero:
[SQL server identity column values start at 0 instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724668/sql-server-identity-column-values-start-at-0-instead-of-1/724689#724689)

Comment: sorry for saying backup, yeah i am exporting my database and need to keep the value of identity seed. is there any way you can suggest.

Comment: As I said, DBCC CHECKIDENT

Comment: i am having around 100 tables. it is not feasible to fire the DBCC CHECKIDENT on every table.

Comment: @Mr.Bhanushali Use SET IDENTITY INSERT then on import. If this is too much because you have a 100 tables, then there is no other solution.