# DBCC CHECKIDENT RESEED -- is new value required?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, auto-increment

All the documentation I read about reseeding suggests something along the lines of:

1. `SET @maxIdentityValue = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename)`
2. run `DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED, @maxIdentityValue)`

And *yet* it appears to me that a simple `DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED)` is all that's needed, and it will automatically determine the correct identity value from the table without supplying a max value.

Is there a reason (performance or otherwise) that extracting the value using `MAX` first is preferred?

Piggyback question: the reason I need to reseed is because I'm using replication and identities keep getting set to Null each time the database replication runs. What am I doing wrong? How can I maintain the correct identity seed for each table?

### Update (Current solution)

For now I'm not using the max value. This is the stored procedure I'm using (I generate it using a query on `sys.columns` and then just cutting and pasting each into a new query window. Messier, slower, less elegant, but I'm not very familiar with stored procedures and don't want to use dynamic SQL queries):

```
declare @seedval integer
declare @maxval integer
declare @newval integer
set @seedval = (select ident_current('mytable'));
set @maxval = (select MAX(id) from mytable);
if @maxval > @seedval or @seedval is NULL
BEGIN
    print 'Need to reseed: max is '  + cast(@maxval as varchar) + ' and seed is ' + cast(@seedval as varchar) 
    dbcc checkident('mytable', RESEED);
    set @newval = (select ident_current('mytable'));
    print 'Max is ' + cast(@maxval as varchar) + ' and seed is ' + cast(@newval as varchar) 
END 
ELSE
    print 'No need to reseed';
```

Comment: Did you test that this works? I did this recently and I was forced to use the work-around.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it worked for me. Correctly identified `31` as the maximum value and set the identity to that.

Comment: Ah, the accepted answer contains the reason why it did not work for me. I wanted to *decrease* the current value. Not possible for some reason.

Comment: <code>
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('CARD.Alias',RESEED,0)<br>
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('CARD.Alias')
</code>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176057.aspx), it is fairly enough to use just:

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT('tablename', RESEED)
```

most of the time, however there are these two conditions where it will not work:

- The current identity value is larger than the maximum value in the table.
- All rows are deleted from the table.

in which you have to go with they way that you mentioned (select max(id) and the rest), so why bother in the first place? :)

Answer (score 4):

[(I'm reposting my answer from this other SO page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923855/how-to-automatically-reseed-after-using-identity-insert)

Perhaps the easiest way (as crazy as this sounds and as code-smelly as it looks) is to just run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` twice like this:

```
-- sets all the seeds to 1
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'', RESEED, 1)'

-- run it again to get MSSQL to figure out the MAX/NEXT seed automatically
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'')'
```

Done.

If you want, you can run it once more to see what all the seeds were set to:

```
-- run it again to display what the seeds are now set to
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT (''?'')'
```

This is just a creative way to take advantage of the comment from the documentation:

> If the current identity value for a table is less than the maximum
>   identity value stored in the identity column, it is reset using the
>   maximum value in the identity column.

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where you might want to determine the max so that you can reseed and leave a gap (e.g. max + 100). One case might be when you have multiple copies of a table and you are going to distribute independent but mutually exclusive identity ranges from them.

But still, I'm not confident that the RESEED without a parameter will work correctly in all scenarios.

Is it a common occurrence that you're reseeding tables back to the max? Why? Poorly coded application that generates a bunch of rows in a loop that you end up rolling back?

In any case, you'll want to wrap the MAX and RESEED in a transaction to prevent the chance that a user will insert a new row after you've taken the max but before you've issued the reseed.

Comment: As noted in the question, for some reason when the database replicates the identities are all set to NULL. I'd love it if I could solve that problem, but as I'm not directly responsible for the replication itself (another DB admin is involved in that) I need a workaround until the other guy can figure out why replication is messing up our identities.

Comment: I missed that line in the question - did you add that after you originally posted? Anyway if that's the problem you are actually trying to solve then I suggest you post that as the question instead of this performance yay or nay about checking the max - maybe you don't need to use reseed in the first place (however I cannot comment as my experience with replication is basically isolated to knowing how to spell it).

Comment: It would be nice to solve the underlying problem but for today I just need to fix the symptom. I'm going to loop through all of my tables running reseed and just wanted to make sure that there's no fundamental problem with it.