# IDENT_CURRENT returning value which does not exist in the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which uses `IDENT_CURRENT` to update last added value in a table.

**The issue is:**

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns a value that does not exist in the table.
The number it returns is much higher than Max(ID) of the table.
How is it possible and what can be done to fix it. I never wanted to use `MAX(ID)` to update the table.

Thanks.

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last `IDENTITY` **generated** even if that was for a row that was never inserted as the transaction was rolled back. Can you explain more about why you need to update the most recently inserted row? Do you want to update the one most recently inserted in your current session or globally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445185/dbcc-checkident-reseed-is-new-value-required

Comment: The thing is I manually added just 1 row and the insert was successful. I am thinking where and how did the rollback happen.

Comment: We can't tell you when the rollback happened. Or whether there were some rows that were since deleted.

Comment: I have a windows service which sends files to FTP and runs every few minutes. I need to store the value of last file sent which is based on the last ID. I need the one in my current session.

Comment: @Learner - So return `SCOPE_IDENTITY` after your `INSERT` statements or use the `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the table is updated only at the time, you can use **IDENT_CURRENT ("Table")** and get the **last inserted id** in that table.

:)