# Update ID field in SQLite database when an entry is removed

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my android application which holds multiple username/password entries, this content is placed into a ListView.

What I would like to achieve, is when an item is longpressed, it is removed from the list, but I'm encountering an issue.

I use the following code to remove an entry from the database:

```
    public void deleteEntry(int ID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGINS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{Integer.toString(ID)});
    db.close();
    }
```

The data is stored in the database in the following manner:

```
--------------------------
1|server|username|password
2|server|username|password
3|server|username|password
4|server|username|password
--------------------------
```

Now if I was to mark entry #2 for deletion, I would end up with the following

```
--------------------------
1|server|username|password
3|server|username|password
4|server|username|password
--------------------------
```

Which causes issues attempting to access the other entries, as I do all my lookups using the first field. Using the position from my OnItemLongClickListener, if I was to press the 2nd item in the list, it would be searching for an item with ID of 2.

How can I update the entries in my database so that my ID field will be sequentially numbered? Is there a better alternative to using an ID field?

Comment: How is the data being displayed in the list? I mean are you sorting it in any way?

Comment: Why are you using the position and not the ID?

Comment: @TeChNo_DeViL I display it in the order I receive it from the database

Comment: @CL because there is no 0 id field, the database starts with ID 1

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to simply reset your identity columns, you can refer to this question:  [SQL Server Reset Identity Increment for all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364742/sql-server-reset-identity-increment-for-all-tables)

Note that relying on all your columns being incremental is fairly bad practice, I would advise you link each row in the database to a row in your program so when loading, you select each item from the database and create a row for it in your program, this eliminates this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a simple change.

When you load the list (using the `CursorLoader` if you are using so), maintain a list of ids that are loaded. This can be achieved by declaring a global `ArrayList<Integer>` holding the ids of the loaded fields. Now using the `onLongItemClicked` or likewise methods, you can simply delete the rows from the database using the IDs by using `get(position)` method on the `ArrayList<Integer>` object to get the ID currently held by a row item. Finally after deleting from the database, delete the ID from the ArrayList as well, and you're ready for another round of deletion.