# SQL Set IDENTITY Field Using Variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql, identity-column

All, I want to start the numbering of an `IDENTITY` field based on the current maximum obtained from another table. So I have tried something like the following

```
DECLARE @CurrentES INT;
SET @CurrentES = (SELECT MaxES 
                  FROM [NDB]..[TmpMaxES]) + 1;
ALTER TABLE BA 
ADD ES INT IDENTITY(@CurrentES, 1);
```

But this will not accept a variable as the seed value in IDENTITY. How can what I require be achieved?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do do this and other non-variable allowed tasks, you can use the EXEC function, as follows:

```
DECLARE @CurrentES INT;
SET @CurrentES = (SELECT MaxES 
                  FROM [NDB]..[TmpMaxES]) + 1;

DECLARE @Statement VARCHAR(200)

SET @Statement = 'ALTER TABLE BA 
ADD ES INT IDENTITY(' + CAST(@CurrentES AS VARCHAR) + ', 1);'

EXEC (@Statement)
```

Comment: one should avoid dynamic SQL as much as possible. In this case there a non-dynamic alternative proposed by freefaller

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `dbcc checkident` feature of SQL Server...

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT
SELECT @MAXID = MAX(ID_FIELD) FROM OLDTABLE
dbcc checkident(NEWTABLE, reseed, @MAXID)
```

One thing to note with this is that the value in the 3rd parameter (in this case the `@MAXID` variable) denotes the **current** identity value - in other words the last identity value that was generated on the table.

So, for example, if you want the **next** value that is automatically created to be `100`, then set the 3rd parameter to `99`.

Comment: watch out for this: checkident results in different behaviour if your table has never had data in it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472578/dbcc-checkident-sets-identity-to-0

Answer (score 2):

```
--first variable 
    declare @code varchar(50);
    set @code=1345688867567576;
--second variable
    declare @namedb varchar(50);
    set @namedb='test';
--let's you add to the identity(ID) field           
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.nameAndroid ON
--declaring variable to hold the next id number
    declare @id int;
    set @id=@@IDENTITY +1;
--clause to check if the table has the matching barcode 
    if not exists (select * from dbo.nameAndroid where barcode = @code)
    INSERT INTO dbo.nameAndroid (id, name, barcode, [floor], Column1,Column2,Row1,Row2,Shelf,Stock,OnOrder)
    VALUES ( @id,@namedb, @code, 'Value3', 'Value4','Value5','Value6','Value7','Value8',123,600);

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.nameAndroid OFF;
```

OR (if the id column is of type int)

```
    declare @code varchar(50);
    set @code='123211';

    declare @namedb varchar(50);
    set @namedb='test';

    declare @floordb varchar(50);
    set @floordb='test';

    declare @Column1db varchar(50);
    set @Column1db='test';

    declare @Column2db varchar(50);
    set @Column2db='test';

    declare @Row1db varchar(50);
    set @Row1db='test';

    declare @Row2db varchar(50);
    set @Row2db='test';

    declare @Shelfdb varchar(50);
    set @Shelfdb='test';

    declare @OnOrderdb decimal(18,2);
    set @OnOrderdb=10010;

    declare @Stockdb decimal(18,2);
    set @Stockdb=1010101;

    declare @id int;
   set @id=((select max(id) from dbo.nameAndroid )+1);



if not exists (select * from dbo.nameAndroid where barcode = @code)

  begin
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.nameAndroid ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.nameAndroid (id, name, barcode, [floor], Column1,Column2,Row1,Row2,Shelf,Stock,OnOrder)
    VALUES (@id, @namedb, @code, @floordb, @Column1db,@Column2db,@Row1db,@Row2db,@Shelfdb,@OnOrderdb,@Stockdb);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.nameAndroid OFF;
end
```

Comment: you should use `scope_identity()` not `@@IDENTITY`, the latter isn't scoped to your script so can give unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] ON
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ... (MAX) Value from another table and other applicable record.
...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTable] OFF
```